# How to send value from input type password to other intup using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to send value from input type password to other intup using javascript ?

first , fill data into

```
<input type="text" onchange="updateInput_current_password(this.value)">
```

then data in

```
<input type="text" name="current_password_for_check" id="current_password_for_check"/>
```

will change follow,

But when i apply for use with

```
<input type="password" onchange="updateInput_current_password(this.value)">
```

Why , value in

```
<input type="text" name="current_password_for_check" id="current_password_for_check"/>
```

Not change ?

How can i do that ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateInput_current_password(current_passwordvalue){
    document.getElementById("current_password_for_check").value = current_passwordvalue;
}
</script>


<input type="password" onchange="updateInput_current_password(this.value)">


<form id="current_password_send_value_fid">
    <input type="text" name="current_password_for_check" id="current_password_for_check"/>  
</form>
```

Comment: Remove this line: `send_current_password_for_check_incorrect_or_not();` and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way:

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/7xkh7u3h/3/)

#### HTML:

```
<input type="password" />
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var inpt = document.querySelctor('input[type="password"]');

inpt.onkeydown = function() {
    alert(inpt.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You change the events for input pass

```
<input type="password" onkeydown="updateInput_current_password(this.value)" onkeyup="updateInput_current_password(this.value)" />
```

Comment: i want to use onchange only